# Find a holomorphic function that satisfies this equation

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers, exponentiation

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ denote a function that satisfies the following equation:
$$f(w,z+1)=w^{f(w,z)}$$
Is there a unique holomorphic function $f$ that satisfies this equation? If so, what is it? If not, what additional specifications are needed to find one?

Furthermore, $$f(w,1)=w$$

Comment: When you say holomorphic, do you mean in a several complex variables sense? Or do you mean holomorphic in $z$, treating $w$ as a parameter?

Comment: Holomorphic in both variables, if possible.